Automatic fingering under notes
I have the notes colored based on their string, and now I'm trying to get only the fretLabels from the TabStaff under each note, instead of having the whole tablature.
But so far I could only find ways to manually add fingering for each note.
\version "2.24.3"

#(define (string-colors grob)
   (let* ((pch (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'pitch))
          (semitones (ly:pitch-semitones pch)))
          (cond ((= semitones -5) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones -4) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones -3) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones -2) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones -1) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones 0) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones 1) "royalblue")
                ((= semitones 2) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 3) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 4) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 5) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 6) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 7) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 8) "darkmagenta")
                ((= semitones 9) "green")
                ((= semitones 10) "green")
                ((= semitones 11) "green")
                ((= semitones 12) "green")
                ((= semitones 13) "green")
                ((= semitones 14) "green")
                ((= semitones 15) "green")
                ((= semitones 16) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 17) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 18) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 19) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 20) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 21) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 22) "darkgoldenrod")
                ((= semitones 23) "darkgoldenrod")
                (else black))))


piece_music = \relative c {\time 4/4 
  f fis g gis a ais b c cis d dis e
  f fis g gis a ais b c cis d dis e
  f fis g gis a ais b c cis d dis e
}


piece_staff =
<<
  \new Staff {
    \set Staff.midiInstrument = "violin"
      \override NoteHead.color = #string-colors
      \override Accidental.color = #string-colors
      \override Stem.color = #string-colors
    \clef treble
    \piece_music}
  \new TabStaff \with {
    \clef moderntab
     stringTunings = #violin-tuning
     tablatureFormat = #fret-letter-tablature-format
     fretLabels = #'("0" "1L" "1" "2L" "2" "3" "3H" "4")}
     {\piece_music}
    >>

  \score {
    \layout{
      \context {
        \Score
        \override SpacingSpanner.spacing-increment = 1.8
      }
    }
    \piece_staff
    }
   \paper {
     indent = 0\cm
     short-indent = 0\cm
   }



A bit hackish, but one possibility:
% Add middle C to TabNoteHead.details.middleCPosition for later positioning
#(define (tab-head-annotate-middle-c-engraver context)
   (make-engraver
    (acknowledgers
     ((tab-note-head-interface engraver grob source-engraver)
      (ly:grob-set-nested-property!
       grob '(details middleCPosition)
       (ly:context-property context 'middleCPosition))))))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists Tab_note_heads_engraver
    \consists #tab-head-annotate-middle-c-engraver
    % Remove TabNoteHeads from Stems
    \override Stem.before-line-breaking =
    #(lambda (grob)
       (let* ((heads (ly:grob-object grob 'note-heads))
              (heads (ly:grob-array->list heads))
              (heads (filter
                      (lambda (x)
                        (not (member 'tab-note-head-interface (ly:grob-interfaces x))))
                      heads)))
         (ly:grob-set-object! grob 'note-heads (ly:grob-list->grob-array heads))))
    \override TabNoteHead.direction =
    #(lambda (grob)
       (ly:grob-property (ly:grob-object grob 'stem) 'direction))
    % Place TabNoteHead depending on pitch, middle c and direction
    \override TabNoteHead.Y-offset =
    #(lambda (grob)
       (let* ((cause (ly:grob-property grob 'cause))
              (pitch (ly:event-property cause 'pitch))
              (position (+ (ly:pitch-notename pitch) (* (ly:pitch-octave pitch) 7)))
              (det (ly:grob-property grob 'details))
              (middle-c (assoc-get 'middleCPosition det -6)))
         (+ (/ position 2) (/ middle-c 2) (* (ly:grob-property grob 'direction) -1.5))))
  }
}

{
  c' d' e' c''
  \clef bass
  c' d' e' c''
  \ottava 1
  c' d' e' c''
}

Edit: Here is a version which creates Text Scripts instead:
% Add replace Tab Note Heads by Text Scripts
#(define (tab-head-to-script-engraver context)
   (make-engraver
    (acknowledgers
     ((tab-note-head-interface engraver grob source-engraver)
      (let ((text (ly:grob-property grob 'text))
            (ts (ly:engraver-make-grob engraver 'TextScript (ly:grob-property grob 'cause))))
        (ly:grob-set-property! ts 'text text)
        (ly:grob-suicide! grob))))))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists Tab_note_heads_engraver
    \consists #tab-head-to-script-engraver
    % Remove TabNoteHeads from Stems
    \override Stem.before-line-breaking =
    #(lambda (grob)
       (let* ((heads (ly:grob-object grob 'note-heads))
              (heads (ly:grob-array->list heads))
              (heads (filter
                      (lambda (x)
                        (not (null? (ly:grob-interfaces x))))
                      heads)))
         (ly:grob-set-object! grob 'note-heads (ly:grob-list->grob-array heads))))
  }
}

{
  c'8 d' e' c''
  \clef bass
  c' d' e' c''
  \ottava 1
  c' d' e' c''
}

